# IronPython UnboundNameException when calling a function from another function

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
class myClass:
    def foo(thingy):
        //does what I want

    def bar():
        r=1
        while r<=something:
            foo(r)
```

The Python script is called from this method:

```
public dynamic CallFunction(string method, params dynamic[] arguments)
{
    return engine.Operations.InvokeMember(class, method, arguments);
}
```

I get the UnboundNameException saying "global name 'foo' is not defined".
I'm not at all sure of what's causing this to happen and would be happy if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: check the spelling of foo(),maybe the string method is Foo() which will throw an exception.

Comment: And thingy is 1 entity right?,if so your arguments is not best choice,try convert them to 1 thingy.